# How to find the depth of a specific node in a BST in c

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, depth

I am trying to find the depth of a specific node noted by a pointer in c, but I cant seem to get it right

```
int depth(Node *root, Node *N){
    // Need to find the root N
    // At the same time count how many depths you can go down
    
    // If the root is NULL, then no tree and return -1
    if (root == NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    // If the root node equals the node N, then return 0
    if (root->data == N->data){
        return 0;
    }
    // Search the tree and add one each time recursion called
    int count = -1;
    if (N->data < root->data){
        root->left->data = depth(root->left, N);
        count++;
    }
    else if (N->data > root->data){
        root->right->data = depth(root->right, N);
        count++;
    }
    else{
        
    }
    return count;
}
```

Any help in solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you modifying `data` when searching the tree?

Comment: Why are you modifying the tree contents by assigning the return value of `depth()` to `root->left->data` or `root->right->data`?

Comment: I am trying to recursively search the tree for the given Node and after each recursion add 1 to count to act as the depth. I am not amazing at C so am just trying my best

Comment: first of all why modify data?
second of all it seems that count is local to the function and although the function returns it, you dont accumulate it when going out of the recursion so it will always be 1.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to assign the data of the BST to the depth value where that data resides either.

Comment: The only way I could think of returning the depth of the node is to search the tree recursively and return how many times recursion occurs + 1 for the root node

Comment: *But that's not what you are doing*.  On one hand, you are modifying the contents of the tree, which is wildly inappropriate for an interrogatory function such as this.  On the other hand, a call to `depth()` does not use the value of its recursive call in its computation of its own return value -- it always returns either -1 (the initial value of its local copy of `count`) or 0 (the initial value of `count` + 1).

Answer (score 1):

The *pseudo code* for such a function is along the lines of this, assuming root = level 0:

```
int search (const node_t* node, int level)
{
    if(node == NULL)
      return -1;
    if(node->data == key)
      return level;

    const node_t* node next;

    if(node->data < key)
      next = node->right;
    else if(node->data > key)
      next = node->left
    
    return search (next, level+1);
}
```

First called as `search(root, 0);`

Though as usual, recursion in C is almost certainly the wrong solution to any problem. The above can rather trivially be rewritten as sane, readable, fast loops instead.

Comment: So would you recommend in C doing this iteratively - having the pointer to the root parsed through as well as the pointer to the value to be determined the depth, finding this value and then returning the level it is at + 1 ?

Comment: @Fraser Yes, something similar to the above but switch the burdensome recursion with something like `for(cost node_t* i=root; i!=NULL; i=next) { ... }`. Recursion is pretty useless in C since it's never faster than a loop, often way slower, way more dangerous and error-prone and often harder to read. The main uses for recursion are: obfuscation, code golf, posing, confusing students.